# Faceted bar plot of count of levels in all the factors of dataset - R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to display a faceted bar plot for the count of levels in all the columns of the dataset.

the code,

```
aas <- sapply(AAA, is.factor)
aas1 <- AAA[,aas]
```

overview of aas1 dataset

[image]

```
aas2 <- data.frame(t(aas1))
aas2 <- cbind(names = rownames(aas2), aas2)

library(reshape2)
aas3 <- melt(aas2,id = "names")
aas3$variable <- 1
aas3$value <- as.factor(aas3$value)

aas4 <- aggregate(.~ names + value, aas3, sum)
```

overview of aas4 dataset

[image]

```
ggplot(aas4, aes(x=factor(value), y= variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(.~names) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="value") +  xlab("")
```

facet bar plot

[image]

when i use aas4 dataset for faceted bar plot, each facet is consisting of all levels of "value", but i only need facets with levels corresponding to the variable "names"

Please suggest any better way to plot counts of levels of all factor variables in the dataset.

Comment: Try with `droplevels`

Comment: droplevels won't work as all the levels in the variable "value" are in the dataset.

Comment: I wonder if `facet_grid(..., scales = "free_x")` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that you want `scales="free_x"` and, in order not to have the same space for each facet, `space="free"`.

```
+ facet_grid(.~names, scales="free_x", space="free_x")
```